# Setter code not hit if I enter a string as a value of an integer property

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml

I have a property which looks like

```
[IsNumericValidation]
[Range(0, 200)]
[Required]
public override int Threshold
{
    get
    {
        return this._threshold;
    }
    set
    {
            //removed some code
            base.OnPropertyChanged("Threshold");
        }
    }
```

And in my XAML I have

```
<TextBox Margin="10" Text="{Binding Threshold, 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                     ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }"   
                         />
```

I have added a breakpoint into the setter of `Threshold`

When I type a numeric value into the textbox, everything works as expected (and the breakpoint in the setter is hit).

When I type in a non-numeric value (such as the letter `d`) the breakpoint is not hit.

I have some additional logic in my setter, and I also use the `ValidationAttribute` to have my own validation rules.

Whilst I feel an option is to change the type so `Threshold` is a `string`, that seems hacky!

I can only assume the reason the breakpoint isn't hit is due to some additional error checking done by WPF, my question is if my assumption is right, can I turn it off for this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setter is not hit because the property is not changed. The validator will prevent the value from being passed on. Even if it was hit, the setter would not be called as there'd be an exception while invoking the property's setter - a `d` can not be converted to a proper `int`.

Comment: Ah... I see... So in that case, I guess the option *is* to have it as type `string` and perform the necessary conversion/casting as and when I need

Comment: Well, how do you expect "d" to be handled as the input for an `int` property? You might want to use a type converter to convert all valid values between `string` and `int` and vice versa. If you want to allow for numeric values only, use a validator that provides visual feedback to the user upon invalid inputs.

Comment: I'd expect that if the user entered `d`, the validation control I wrote would kick in and inform the user it's invalid... Of course, the value (`d`) has to be stored somewhere (I guess the property could be of type `object`).. I hadn't thought it through that far, I was only focusing on *that* it wasn't set, not *why* it wasn't setting. Thank you for your clear answer

Comment: Then I'd rather debug the validation control to see why it doesn't handle "d" as it should :-)

Comment: Ah, I need a validation rule I think :)